# Can't find xml tag using beautiful soup and python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, xml-parsing

I'm trying to pull the image:title tag with specific keywords from an xml page. The keywords work fine if i just search on loc tags. Code below

```
print("Searching for product...")
        keywordLinkFound = False
        while keywordLinkFound is False:
            html = self.driver.page_source
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')
            try:
                regexp = "%s.*%s|%s.%s" % (keyword1, keyword2, keyword2, keyword1)
                keywordLink = soup.find('image:title', text=re.compile(regexp))
                print(keywordLink)
                return keywordLink
            except AttributeError:
                print("Product not found on site, retrying...")
                time.sleep(monitorDelay)
                self.driver.refresh()
            break
```

Here is the xml code that im parsing:

```
<url>
<loc>
   https://packershoes.com/products/copy-of-adidas-predator-accelerator-trainer
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-11-24T08:22:42-05:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<image:image>
    <image:loc>
    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0208/5268/products/adidas_Yung-1_B37616_side.jpg?v=1537395620
    </image:loc>
    <image:title>ADIDAS YUNG-1 "CLOUD WHITE"</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
```

It seems that I am unable to get to the image:title tag

Answer (score 0):

This finds the text within the `<image:title>`:

```
soup.findAll('image')[0].findAll('title')[0].text
```

or you can do

```
soup.image.title.text
```

with the output:

```
'ADIDAS YUNG-1 "CLOUD WHITE"'
```

You should use the built-in methods in `BeautifulSoup` ([documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)) instead of regular expressions. The benefit of using `BeatifulSoup` for parsing `HTML` is that you can take advantage of the structured form of the language.

**Edit**

Here is the complete working code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<url>
<loc>
   https://packershoes.com/products/copy-of-adidas-predator-accelerator-trainer
</loc>
<lastmod>2018-11-24T08:22:42-05:00</lastmod>
<changefreq>daily</changefreq>
<image:image>
    <image:loc>
    https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0208/5268/products/adidas_Yung-1_B37616_side.jpg?v=1537395620
    </image:loc>
    <image:title>ADIDAS YUNG-1 "CLOUD WHITE"</image:title>
</image:image>
</url>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'xml')
soup.image.title.text
```

Output:

```
'ADIDAS YUNG-1 "CLOUD WHITE"'
```

Comment: The above didn't work, i tried this and i got no where keywordLink = soup.find(attrs={'image:title'}, text=re.compile(regexp)).text

Comment: Both methods I showed were able to find the `image:title` text using the HTML you provided.